# Hosting dynamic website in Amazon server

Tags: amazon-s3

I am working on a project where we are hosting our files(only uploaded by the user) in S3 Amazon server. Now the problem is the contents hosted with amazon is loading fastly. But the JS, CSS and CSS images(Very small images) which hosted in our server is taking too much time to load. Is there anyway to host our entire dynamic website to Amazon S3 and is it possible to configure the DNS to amazon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Host your static files to S3 as well.

1. Create a bucket named `static.yourcompany.com`
2. CName the bucket URL as `static.yourcomapany.com`
3. In your webpages, use absolute path for CSS, JS, images with base URL as `http://static.yourcompany.com`
4. You may want to leverage tools like JetS3t for syncing the files with the latest changes.

Refer:

- [How to alias your subdomain with S3](http://carltonbale.com/how-to-alias-a-domain-name-or-sub-domain-to-amazon-s3/)
- [JetS3t Docs](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/toolkit/code-samples.html)
- [Virtual Hosting of Buckets](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html)
- [Host Your Static Website on S3](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html)

Comment: Here is one more link http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html that will be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

You can also read this blog, the author has described the process in a very detailed manner 
http://geekospace.com/hosting-static-web-sites-in-aws-simple-storage-service/

Answer (score 1):

For the dynamic part of your website look into http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/ but route 53 is essentially a way to configure DNS to amazon. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html